# Finding the Expected Value with a Random Constant

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

> Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with PDF: $$\begin{cases}
>  e^{-(x-c)}\ \ \text{when }x > c \\ 0\ \quad \quad\text{when}\ x \leq c
>  \end{cases}$$
>
> a. Find $\mathbb{E}(X)$
>   b. Find $\mathbb{E}(X-c)$
>   c. Find $\mathbb{E}(X/c)$

I know how to calculate expected value over a given interval $[a,b]$: $$\int_a^b xf(x) \mathrm{d}x.$$ But the lack of interval as well as the $c$ is throwing me off. I'm thinking the interval should be from $0$ to infinity, but that's as much as I've got.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \, f_X(x)\, dx = \int_c^\infty x \, f_X(x)\, dx$

Comment: I know that part, but how would I actually evaluate it? The c in the function throws me off

Comment: do you know how to integrate $x e^{-x}$ ? (using integration by parts for removing the $x$)

Comment: My integration by parts skills are a little rusty

Comment: there are 50 questions on this forum where you can find the result... and you can check if the result is correct by differentiating...

Comment: If you are familiar with exponential distribution, you can immediately recognize that $X$ is a shifted exponential random variable, with location parameter $c$. Or, in other words, $X$ has the same distribution as $Y + c$ where $Y$ follows the exponential distribution with mean $1$. If you can recognize this at the beginning and you are allowed to use this fact, then everything is straight forward. Of course you can do part a) by integration first as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

a.

$E(X)=\int_{c}^{\infty}xe^{-(x-c)}dx=\int_{c}^{\infty}xe^{-x+c}dx=-\left(x+1\right)\mathrm{e}^{c-x}\vert_{c}^{\infty}=0-(-(x+1))=x+1$

b.

$E(X-c)=E(X)-c=x+1-c$

c.

$E(X/c)=E(X)/c=\frac{x+1}{c}$

Hint:

For the integral part $\int_{c}^{\infty}xe^{c-x}dx$, you could use integral by parts, and let $f(x)=x$ and $g'(x)=e^{c-x}$. Then $f'(x)=1$ and $g(x)=-e^{c-x}$. Then you just have to integrate $-xe^{c-x}-\int_{c}^{\infty}-e^{c-x}dx$.

Comment: What is $x$ here?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Linearity of Expectation says that for any constants $a,b$ and random variable $X$, then: $$\mathsf E(aX+b) ~=~ a~\mathsf E(X)+b$$

If you can find $\mathsf E(X)$, then you can find $\mathsf E(X-c)$ and $\mathsf E(\tfrac 1 c X)$

> $$\begin{align} \mathsf E(X)~ &=~ \int_c^\infty xe^{-(x-c)}\operatorname d x \\&=~ \int_0^\infty (y+c)e^{-y}\operatorname d y \\&= ~1+c \end{align}$$